# Font size being reported as fractionally off set value

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, truetype

I'm making a form in Visual Studio 2019 with C# and set the font of a label with a font dialog:

```
    FontDialog fontDlg = new FontDialog();
    if (fontDlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        Label.Font = fontDlg.Font;
        Label.Text = fontDlg.Font.Name;
    }
```

I set Sans Serif 10pt. I then read back the size with

```
    string size = Label.Font.Size
```

and I get "9.75" instead of "10".

Why would this be?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/1c22f48bd28d852a.html

The FontDialog in WinForms.NET is just a wrapper around the Native WinForms FontDialog. Apparently, according to the .Net reference source, the Native FontDialog is returning Device -dependent values, but in .Net it's device-independent unit for Font.Size.

Comment: Try setting a size in a Font dialogue and you'll see the same effect.

Comment: @B.O.B. - I get the gist of what you're saying but cannot find it. I so wish that link made any sense to me! Can you please point me to a specific section in that link?

Comment: The link should have taken you straight to the UpdateFont method. The .Net FontDialog is calling it when the Native FontDialog is closed. It has the following comment: `// The dialog claims its working in points (a device-independent unit), but actually gives us something in world units (device-dependent).`